# why and how isn't mkdir working

Tags: mkdir

how does mkdir work? I've been trying to install java, and when I type:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/java
```

nothing happens except the terminal just writes it down. when I get to later steps, it says that directory `/usr/local/java` doesn't exist

Comment: Are you using sudo if you're non-root user? /usr/local is owned by root, therefore mkdir won't work without the proper privileges.

Comment: Are these exact steps youre doing ?  No error ? `mkdir` should produce "Permission denied" error because /usr beling to root, yet you said "nothing happens". Can you clarify, please

Answer (score 4):

All system folders are owned by root; thus,you need root permissions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
```

Comment: Paying attention to this users score, it's advisable to explain _why_ he needs root permissions to prevent repeat questions in the future.

Comment: `sudo` is indeed necessary, however note that OP said nothing happens if they do the command as regular user.  However, `mkdir` should produce "Permission denied" error.  There's discrepancy

Comment: I too have the same problem even using sudo.